# Mysql query to select all the items in category table and total items in product table belonging to each category ordering by total count

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables category and products. Category table has id, name and product table has id, cat_id, name, details, etc. I need a mysql query that will select each category and total count of products belonging to each category and order the result by total count. Can anyone help me?

Category table

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | cat1 |
|  2 | cat2 |
|  3 | cat3 |
+----+------+
```

Product table

```
+----+-------+--------+   
| id | name  | cat_id |    
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | prod1 |      1 |    
|  2 | prod2 |      1 |    
|  3 | prod3 |      3 |    
|  4 | prod4 |      2 |    
|  5 | prod5 |      2 |
|  6 | prod6 |      2 |    
+----+-------+--------+
```

Expected output table

```
+----+------+-------+    
| id | name | count |    
+----+------+-------+    
|  2 | cat2 |     3 |    
|  1 | cat1 |     2 |    
|  3 | cat3 |     1 |  
+----+------+-------+
```

Comment: What's your try ? Could u provide us a table display ?
U can use http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html to display it if u don't want to use Sql fiddle.

Comment: This is a basic aggregation query -- you should learn enough SQL to know how to write this.  A well formatted question would have sample data, desired results, and code that you have attempted.  A SQL Fiddle example is also really useful.

Comment: I have given demo tables above can you help me now?

Comment: Can you keep the title small. You question is more like doing your work. But it is very simple. You could try it.But try to improve how you post questions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if group gives error. But try it

```
    select b.cnt,a.name from Category as a left join 
    (select count(*) as cnt,c.name,c.id  from Product as p 
    left join Category as c.id = p.cat_id group by p.cat_id) 
     as b b.id = a.id order by cnt
```

Comment: This query generate only those category which have products associated to them. I need show all category even if the count of associated products are 0.

Comment: Try now let know if you got error. I have edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
SELECT c.id category_id, c.name category_name, count( p.cat_id ) product_count
FROM categories c
INNER JOIN products p ON c.id = p.cat_id
GROUP BY p.cat_id
ORDER BY product_count DESC
```

and result:

```
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| category_id | category_name | product_count |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|           1 | cat1          |             7 |
|           2 | cat2          |             6 |
|           3 | cat3          |             3 |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
```

**Without LEFT JOIN**

Comment: Yes. I should have thought of Inner join. you must be right. It would work. you can try Nitish

Comment: This too still shows only those categories which have related products but not those which have no related products.

Comment: Try this:
SELECT c.id category_id, c.name category_name, count( p.cat_id ) product_count
FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN products p ON c.id = p.cat_id
GROUP BY p.cat_id
ORDER BY product_count DESC